# XPath filter attribute with namespace

Tags: xpath, namespaces, attributes

I am trying to get the following working but alas it is failing to return the expected result. Although similar to questions I have asked before I am restricted by being limited to xpath 1.0.

I am looking to use xpath to get the first text node inside the "subtitle" node. The XML is as follows:

```
<topic class="coverPage">
    <subtitle id="IDb2907ca1-51fe-472e-bf99-246126937eab">
        <xt:delText xt:action="start" xt:author="James Doherty" xt:dateTime="2016-01-27T17:07:00" xt:id="fb72fba6-f502-422e-9e91-1731ed007e98"/>
            Ignore
        <xt:delText xt:action="end" xt:id="fb72fba6-f502-422e-9e91-1731ed007e98"/>
        Sub-title
        <xt:insText xt:action="start" xt:author="James Doherty" xt:dateTime="2016-01-27T14:55:00" xt:id="44ac82c2-acfc-4721-b962-20ac2b18d9f3"/>
            Insert Additional Text
        <xt:insText xt:action="end" xt:id="44ac82c2-acfc-4721-b962-20ac2b18d9f3"/>
        Extra Text
    </subtitle>
</topic>
```

Alternative XML is also provide below:

```
<topic class="coverPage">
    Sub-title
    <subtitle id="IDb2907ca1-51fe-472e-bf99-246126937eab">
        <xt:delText xt:action="start" xt:author="James Doherty" xt:dateTime="2016-01-27T17:07:00" xt:id="fb72fba6-f502-422e-9e91-1731ed007e98"/>
            Ignore
        <xt:delText xt:action="end" xt:id="fb72fba6-f502-422e-9e91-1731ed007e98"/>
        <xt:insText xt:action="start" xt:author="James Doherty" xt:dateTime="2016-01-27T14:55:00" xt:id="44ac82c2-acfc-4721-b962-20ac2b18d9f3"/>
            Insert Additional Text
        <xt:insText xt:action="end" xt:id="44ac82c2-acfc-4721-b962-20ac2b18d9f3"/>
        Extra Text
    </subtitle>
</topic>
```

I have tried the following but with no luck:

```
/topic[@class='coverPage']/*[local-name()='subtitle']/text()[1]|/topic[@class='coverPage']/*[local-name()='subtitle']/*[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name())-string-length('Text')+1)='Text'][@*[local-name()='action']='end'][1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

I believe the issue is with the attribute value "action" and it having a namespace. The expected results would be "Sub-title". Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: the latter half of your query seems to return "Sub-title" as per your expectations: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=33963c98-b5b0-44b5-b83c-3010e5d85f12-xpath#.VqomcOaICUk (I took the `.` from the beginning off, so that it would start at the root node)

Comment: Thanks @KeithHall, however the example you provided includes a definition for a xml namespace, which my XML doesn't have. I've also added another XML sample to my OP that contains an example that should work with the "OR" part of my xpath. Thanks...

Comment: Would something like this help you ? 

`//topic[@class="coverPage"]/descendant::subtitle/*[position() = 1]`

Comment: [The XML is invalid without the namespace being declared before it is used](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#nsc-NSDeclared) - maybe that is why the xpath query doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks @KeithHall, yes I think you're right, it appears my source is the issue. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML is missing the xml namespace definition, as kindly pointed out by @KeithHall in the comments of the OP.

```
<topic class="coverPage" "xmlns:xt="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063599/xpath-filter-attribute-with-namespace">
    <subtitle id="IDb2907ca1-51fe-472e-bf99-246126937eab">
        <xt:delText xt:action="start" xt:author="James Doherty" xt:dateTime="2016-01-27T17:07:00" xt:id="fb72fba6-f502-422e-9e91-1731ed007e98"/>
            Ignore
        <xt:delText xt:action="end" xt:id="fb72fba6-f502-422e-9e91-1731ed007e98"/>
        Sub-title
        <xt:insText xt:action="start" xt:author="James Doherty" xt:dateTime="2016-01-27T14:55:00" xt:id="44ac82c2-acfc-4721-b962-20ac2b18d9f3"/>
            Insert Additional Text
        <xt:insText xt:action="end" xt:id="44ac82c2-acfc-4721-b962-20ac2b18d9f3"/>
        Extra Text
    </subtitle>
</topic>
```

To filter the XML based on an attribute value, with namespace, the following xpath is used:

```
[@*[local-name()='action']='end']
```

The full xpath to achieve the expected result is below, unchanged from the OP.

```
/topic[@class='coverPage']/*[local-name()='subtitle']/text()[1]|/topic[@class='coverPage']/*[local-name()='subtitle']/*[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name())-string-length('Text')+1)='Text'][@*[local-name()='action']='end'][1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```